# ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript executa na hora? ou apenas depois do end sub

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Ao executar esta linha:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Me.GetType, "OK", "openModal()", True);
```

o script e executado no momento em que o ponteiro do debug passa por ela, ou apenas no depois que terminar o processamento da sub?

se for o caso apenas depois do processamento, existe algo que execute na hora ?

Comment: Não tem como algo que está sendo processado no servidor ser imediatamente enviado ao cliente, somente depois de todo o processamento realizado no servidor que o resultado é enviado ao cliente. Para entender melhor, qual o motivo de querer que durante o debug seja executado na hora?

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, cara é o seguinte, preciso executar um script que retorna um valor ai preciso passar esse valor pro codebehind, eu atrelei oa função js que pega esse valor no evento click (do javascript) de um botao de finalizar, porem esse botao de finalizar tbm tem um evento do asp.net, ai que entra o problema parece que o asp executa antes do que o javascript, essa função js joga esse valor em um hiden, meu problema e preencher este hidden antes de o asp executar, pois esse asp necessita desse dado.

Comment: Pela sua descrição está usando webforms e este seu botão realiza o postback. Já tentou usar o onsubmit ao invés do clique do botão? O onsubmit do form você pode executar algo antes de realizar o post.

Comment: Na verdade nao tinha conhecimento... vou dar uma ohlada aqui entao e ver se ajuda... mas esse onsubmit vc diz que voce diz é um evento ? do javascript/ ou do asp?

Comment: É um evento javascript do form.